# Replacing a string in c# issue

Tags: c#, string

My code :

```
msg = msg.Replace(":)", "<a href=\"javascript:void(0)\" class=\"EmojiesIcon\" id=\"smiley\" title=\":)\" ></a>")
         .Replace(":v", "<a href=\"javascript:void(0)\" class=\"EmojiesIcon\" id=\"pacman\" title=\":v\"></a>");
```

When I enter :) in the textbox and I hit send the result of `msg` is always :

```
<a href="javascript<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="EmojiesIcon" id="pacman" title=":v"></a>oid(0)" class="EmojiesIcon" id="smiley" title=":)" ></a>
```

and I can't find why this problem is accruing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
msg = msg.Replace(":)", "<a href=\"javascript:void(0)\" class=\"EmojiesIcon\" id=\"smiley\" title=\":)\" ></a>")
```

This line will produce:

```
"<a href=\"javascript:void(0)\" class=\"EmojiesIcon\" id=\"smiley\" title=\":)\" ></a>"
```

Now, when you get to the next line, you are replacing all instances of `:v`, which includes the `javascript**:v**oid` you got from the first line, for example:

```
 // msg is now the replaced string:
 msg = "<a href=\"javascript:void(0)\" class=\"EmojiesIcon\" id=\"smiley\" title=\":)\" ></a>";
 msg.Replace(":v",
            "<a href=\"javascript:void(0)\" class=\"EmojiesIcon\" id=\"pacman\" title=\":v\"></a>"
 );
```

Hence, you get:

```
msg = "<a href="javascript<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="EmojiesIcon"
id="pacman" title=":v"></a>oid(0)" class="EmojiesIcon" id="smiley"
title=":)" ></a>";
```

You might want to consider using the [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to work with HTML data. It is much more powerful than a simple replace.

Comment: can please explain for me why :) is being replace by <a href="javascript:void" and can u please give me an example of how can i use HtmlAgilityPack in such scenario

Comment: :) is being replaced by `<a href=javascript` because it says so in your first line of code. Unfortunately this isn't the medium for explaining how the HtmlAgilityPack works, you should look for some tutorials on Google - it will help make this whole process easier

Comment: but why it is just being replace by <a href=javascript ? theReplace function should replace a giving string by another why it's not considering the whole string ( <a href=javascript:void(0) class=EmojiesIcon....)

Comment: @Sora It is the whole thing, my provided answer is just an example. I have expanded it to include the full string.